# Upon upgrade of lubuntu 17.10 from 17.04 display messed up on an eeepc 900a

Tags: display, lubuntu, dist-upgrade

Upgraded lubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 on an [EeePC 900a](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-eee-pc-900a-8-9-atom-n270-linux-1-gb-ram-4-gb-ssd-series/specs/). Appears to work fine except that the left side of the display is junk. The full screen looks fine before linux is booted, the Asus EeePC splash.

System has 2GB RAM, 32 GB SSD & wireless USB mouse. [EeePC 900a](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-eee-pc-900a-8-9-atom-n270-linux-1-gb-ram-4-gb-ssd-series/specs/) link's specification incorrectly refers to the model as 900 in one spot nor the system does not have a webcam.

Per the instructions in a popup when attempting to do the upgrade that said there was not enough space on `/boot`, in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` I changed `COMPRESS` from `gzip` to `xz`.

I am able to `ssh` into the system.

Note that even though the left side of the display is garbled, while the mouse pointer is clear on the entire screen.

Booting the same system on 17.04 lubuntu from thumb drive works fine.

[image: Screen shot - junk left / Firefox right.]

Comment: Feel free to fill a bugreport: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: "if are still not sure which package is affected by the bug, type ubuntu-bug in the “Run Command” screen and press Enter. " Since non of the instructions match except unknown I did " ubuntu-bug" which produces "No package specified" popup error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact same problem an no solution so far. There's a workaround: if you suspend the machine and resume it the display works fine again.

You can suspend the computer using the power menu on the login screen (top right corner icon).