# When updating lubuntu 16.04 screen went bad

Tags: display, lubuntu

I have updated a fresh nice well performing lubuntu 16.04 on a 
LG x110 PC.

And the screen went bad just like [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400177/upon-upgrade-of-lubuntu-17-10-from-17-04-display-messed-up-on-an-eeepc-900a).

I think it must be a newer Linux kernel or some thing alike.
It would be nice to have update alerts just as Linux mint does.

I have tried to install the newest lubuntu 17 but this version messes it up from the very beginning. Maybe it could be a screen driver.
Does any one know which update to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

17.10 is using Wayland display protocol by default. You can try to modify the settings in the system file by switching to X as a default. Use Lubuntu installation media to get access to the console and modify the settings. Also you can try to downgrade the kernel version and see if that will help. I think this question should be ask on AskUbuntu page.

How to change Wayland back to Xorg:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Thanx. But I dont think I have skills to modify Wayland.
I have tried the antiX-17.1 distro and it works fine.

Comment: I have modified my answer a bit that should give you a solution how to change a display protocol